# Gulp v4 doesn't update the browser

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

When I start gulp  Google Chrome doesn't open my http://localhost:3000 and doesn't update my css file automaticaly. I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

It's my first time using Gulp, guys. Any idea to fix it? Thanks

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

//compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

//move js to src/js
gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

//gulp html and scss
gulp.task('serve', gulp.parallel('sass'), function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"
    })

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass'])
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload)
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'serve'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

`gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass'])`

to

`gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'))`

Your version was gulp v3, not gulp v4.

Also I would change

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'serve'))`

to

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'sass', 'serve'))`

so that you can simplify to:

`gulp.task('serve', function(){`  // removed the `parallel` part.

The first time you run `gulp.default` you may need refresh the browser if you have some changes already made to your files.  Best to start the `default` task first and then make changes to your files.